# what's wrong with the embeded tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, java-ee-8

Unable to run my project

I am just learning `Springboo`t, following instruction from internet I set up a new project, I use `Eclipse Oxyge`n + `Maven` (with Embedded `Tomcat`) + `Springboot` , I followed the instruction to run the project, but got following error message. I changed the port many times by revising `"application.properties"` file, but it didn't work. I checked all the ports, their states are `"listening".`

> 2019-07-03 04:04:16.256 ERROR 16132 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase   : Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-17500]]
>
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1001) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
>
> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

### [Check Listening Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

> Make sure that new port you are going to set is not being used by
>   other processes. You can check the listening port as below

After Changing the port, Close and Reopen the Project and do Clean, Rebuild your 
Project.

**PowerShell**

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort portNumber).OwningProcess
```

**cmd**

```
 C:\> netstat -a -b
```

---

### Solution

Kill Process on Port 8080 from cmd

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<yourPortNumber>
taskkill /PID <typeyourPIDhere> /F
```

OR Change the Port

Update via a properties file.

```
server.port=8888 # Server HTTP port.
```

Update via a yaml file.

```
server:
  port: 8888
```

Comment: Hello @Terry Have you solved the issue with the above solution?

Answer (score 0):

confirm To you can not use Same Port "8080" More Then One Application  And also confirm to another application is not using same port 
(Example:-  you are going to run your application on Spring with Port 8080 and in Background Another application already was allocated port like XAMPP OR WAPP)

Comment: you can also change the Tomcat Port Number:- Right click on Tomcat Server Then Click on Properties Option now you can able to see all port number , now you can change port number and Restart and Run your Application